# lsblk redirect to grep does not work

Tags: bash

I use the following line in my bash code

```
disks=$(lsblk -nd --output name,rota,fstype | grep $disk_name)
```

When I run my script, the program exits on this line, without any explanation.
However,  using the code `lsblk -nd --output name,rota,fstype | grep $disk_name` in the terminal works.

Why does that happen?

Comment: What are you expecting? You have saved the output in the variable `$disks`. Are you printing that? What is the script doing? The command you show doesn't produce any output, so the script will just run it and exit.

Comment: What is the value of variable `$disk_name`?

Comment: @terdon- Yes. It does not prints any text at all. when executing this line- the bash script immediately stops with not explanation

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar -nvme0n1

Comment: @user3563894 please [edit] your question to provide additional information. Comments can get lost.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the line in my `set -e`. Apparently,when using `var=$(program | grep string)` the command `grep` exits with an error. Now the line above works.
Alternatively, we can do `var=$(program | grep string || true)`.

Comment: Could you please clarify/further expand what you did to solve this problem? One sentence is unlikely to help future users.

Comment: @David done! I think the explanation is better now